# Netbeans 6.9 and nbgit plugin

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Does anyone here has working nbgit plugin with Netbeans 6.9?

I've seen some patches for 6.9 in the repo, but the release 0.4 is not available for download yet on the project page. Is there any compiled version of nbgit 0.4 available to download somewhere?

When I try to install nbgit 0.3, I keep getting the message:

> Some plugins require plugin Editor
>   Library to be installed. The plugin
>   Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.29.2.8.2 (release version 1) but only 2.10.1.10.2 (of release version
>   different from 1) was found.  The
>   following plugin is affected:
>         nbgit

(Netbeans 6.9, Ubuntu Lucid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new version available at http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/downloads/list?q=0.4

Answer (score 1):

I have found version working with Netbeans 6.9 on [Tor Norbye's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/nbgit_for_netbeans_6_9), the last one linked in the comments.

Comment: thanks man! now i'm trying to use that o.4 version for the Netbeans 6.9 as well... :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a post on NetBeans Forums:
http://forums.netbeans.org/post-77502.html

nbgit version that works with NetBeans 6.9: http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/resource/org-nbgit-netbeans69.nbm

Comment: Yes, this is the same version as posted on Tor's blog.